# PostgreSQL query for array in any array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I need a PostgreSQL command that matches from a list of emails against an array type column.

my column is declared as this:

```
emails character varying(255)[] DEFAULT '{}'::character varying[]
```

And I need to search against it using one of many potential matches.
Normally I'd search using the `IN` operator like so: `SELECT * FROM identities WHERE emails IN ['test@test.com'];` but I can't seem to find an example of how to generate an `IN` query when searching against arrays.

Ideally it'd be something like this (which clearly doesn't work):

```
SELECT * FROM identities WHERE ('jaylan.jones@runte.name','qwe@qwe.com') IN ANY (emails);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overlap `&&` operator will check if there are elements in common

```
SELECT * 
FROM identities 
WHERE array['jaylan.jones@runte.name','qwe@qwe.com']::varchar[] && emails;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE